# Same link repeats multiple times in a page clicking one of them changes the color of all same links

Tags: c#, javascript, css

i am working on a rad grid where a link related to same page repeats itself. when i click on one of the links, and then return to the page after navigating to the destination page, all the same links color changes.

what i want is when i click a single link only that should be shown as visited link.

how do i implement this? i am using the link as follows:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Sequence" HeaderText="Seq">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="btnId" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the long version because I don't know how much you already know.

When you visit a link its color changes to a 'visited' color. This color is determined by the user's browser. Each website you visit can choose to override this using CSS.

```
a:visited { color: green; }
```

Every page you visit (regardless of site) that includes the exact same link will use that site's visited css color. You can add a querystring to the the link if you want it to be unique.

```
http://www.google.com/?link=1
http://www.google.com/?link=2
```

Comment: the query string is already added. the query string differentiates each line in the grid. despite that all the link's color changes at once. only the link clicked should be changing color in my case.

Comment: thanks for your help. actually the query string that i was passing had all the same data, that is why all the links were being shown as visited. now i added a unique data to the query string that differentiates the links and its working fine now.